# Maximum number of deployable docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, max, containers

## I'm trying to deploy a large number of containers.

1. I don't want to use `swarm` nor `kubernetes` scaling them, because **each one has a different configuration, environment variables, entry port**, etc.
2. I already know that **the maximum number of container per docker network bridge is 1023**.
3. My host doesn't have memory or CPU usage problems with 1023 containers. Approximately it looks it could work with more than 3000 containers.

Once we start from this, I try to increase the number of deployed docker in the same host creating several `docker network bridge` with [Networking with docker howto](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks)

```
docker network create --driver bridge mydocker-net0 
docker network create --driver bridge mydocker-net1
...
```

Harnessing docker uses Class B IP for containers, possible private IP belong to the interval: 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255. So, theoretically, it could assign 2^19 possible `docker network bridges`, but I'm not sure that so many are possible.

> Finally, I'm looking forward [MAX_NUMBER_CONTAINERS] =
> [MAX_NUMBER_DOCKER_BRIDGES] * 1023

Anyone has tested which is **[MAX_NUMBER_DOCKER_BRIDGES]** or knows about other way to deploy a large number of containers in the same host without scaling with kubernetes nor swarm or similar, please?

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to run 6055 docker containers using 10 bridges. See details on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688385/2972

More than 6055 makes the server unstable: https://serverfault.com/questions/1091520/docker-blocks-when-running-multiple-containers

Answer (score -2):

have you considered the easiest option of all? Just **simple bash script**. This will start 10 containers, and you can put some configs inside the run option with some bash tricks...

```
#!/bin/sh
for (( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )); do
    docker run -d --name my_$i alpine sh
done
```

Comment: i was able to run 1029 containers doing ping to google on my mac... so i think on Linux native environment you will perform much better

Comment: Yes, I try with several ways to deploy thousands of containers, but it doesn't matter the way to deploy them, anyway is not possible exceed maximum of 1023 for a single network bridge.

Comment: what commands are you exactly running so anyone else can replicate the issue. I didnt experience any network issue when running my containers for this..... and what error are you getting when you start container number 1024 ?

Comment: try with `for (( i = 0; i < 2000; i++ )); do
    docker run -d --name my_$i alpine sh
done`

Comment: i ll try that when i get to some powerful machine, but if you are limited to 1024 containers per docker instance, have you tried deploying another `docker-machine` on the host, for example run 500 containers per docker-machine

Comment: Thanks for your help, but No, I want to do without docker-machine, nor VM, neither swarm scale. Just containers